# Powering LED Strip at both ends shorts my psu?

Tags: power, led, led-strip

I've got a 200 LEDs strip of sk9822's hooked up to a 5V 8A power supply.
As expected, at full white, there's considerable voltage drop and the far end of the strip turns from white to amber.

I wanted to hook up another set of V+ and GND at the far end of the strip, but doing so trips my psu? The strip blinks full white as a result.

Hooking up ONLY GND or ONLY V+ at the far end significantly improves the drop off where only the middle of the strip turns slightly amber-ish.
But! I do notice a faint buzzing from the PSU if I do this.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: difficult to guess if you did something wrong ... you did not say how you connected everything up ... please draw a diagram

Comment: Assuming 60mA per led (20mA per colour) you would need a minimum 12A power supply, not 8A. Your PSU is too weak.

Comment: What if you only power it at the middle?

But indeed, your PSU may not be able to supply the whole strip, the reason it blinks is that it shuts off on it's limit and starts back up again.
If you really would have shorted it; I think the strip itself would have behaved differently.

Comment: Basically, the idea is right. Powering from both ends is fine and will fix (at least enhance) the voltage drop problem. Still, Majenko is right. With 8A you shouldn't let them shine in full white. Some colors might work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Put a diode to every psu cable or just take only one psu but make a connection between the input and the far end eith a cable of more than 0,5 mm^2... Spesker csble or so.

Problem with two psu is: one gives 5,00 Volt,  the other 5,05... And there is s power of 0,05 Volt / 8 Ampere running.

Second problem can be the influrnce of different PSU switching frequencies. 
Regards,  Michael

Comment: Why do you assume two different PSUs? As far as I understood, he wants to power it with 1 PSU but 4 connectors (2 on one end, 2 on the other end).